# how should I install blender Shelfy add on?

Tags: interface, add-on

I have been using maya for sometime and I found that they have something called shelves, you make a shelf and you add buttons that you use regularly in it.

I found a add on called Shelfy and I tried to install it.

I downloaded the zip file and extracted it from this repo https://bitbucket.org/cgarhivator/shelfy/src/master/

I opened blender 3.1.2 and went to edit -> preferences -> Add-ons and I installed it by pressing install and choosing the `__init__.py` in the directory.

I then searched on shelfy in the community Add-ons and found "3D view: shelfy addon" and I enabled it

[image]

still shelfy still doesn't appear in blender view port I would be happy to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Don't unzip the file.  Blender does that for you.  Install from the zip file.

Comment: Author of "shelfy" here, im glad someone is using it (i hope you made it work) Btw, im working on new version which will be much more user friendly, stay tuned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't unzip and select the `__init__.py`

Just select the zip file and click "Install Add-on". That will install the addon successfully

[image]